# Input field read-only using React-redux-form

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, express

Having trouble creating a writable input field as so.

```
import { Control } from "react-redux-form";
import { FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";

const existingItem = {
    name: "John",
    city: "Oakland",
};

<Control
    component={FormControl}
    model=".defaultItem"
    componentClass="input"
    id="original-item"
    value={existingItem.name}
/>
```

My goal is to display an input field with the existingItem.name in it so I can edit and submit.

However using the `value` prop the input field becomes read-only. Usually I use `defaultValue` for this but in this case `defaultValue` renders the input field writeable but empty.

Comment: Is `.defaultItem` in your store?

Comment: wow turns it out was just `.item` not `.defaultItem` thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that `.defaultItem` does not exist in your store.